# Software Quality Assurance Conferences - List and recommendations

Tags: learning, conference

I have been looking for some good conferences to attend and recommend to colleagues.  Looking up on Google and some sites, I thought it would be a good idea to create a list of SQA conferences, the place and the time of the year they are organized with the feedback from the individuals.

The format that I was thinking of is to have an answer for each conference, and people can +1 if they recommend the conference and post comments on why they think so or if they feel otherwise.

For now I will just list some in my answer, and based on the feedback one of us can convert to an answer for each.

P.S.: If you just want to check out a list of conferences, here's a good link:
http://www.getzephyr.com/resources/qa_conferences.php

Comment: Mods, can you please make this question a community wiki question?

Comment: If you want people to vote for the conference they like or recommend maybe you should re-word your question to "The *best* SQA conference" or something like that? And explain what you mean by the best.

Comment: I'm not really looking for nor can anyone really term a conference 'the best'.  The way I see, the upvotes would be more like popularity and how liked the conference is.

Answer (score 3):

[GTAC](https://developers.google.com/google-test-automation-conference/), the Google Test Automation Conference, is a small conference hosted by Google. It is by invitation only, but you can apply to be invited. In 2013 they invited about 200 people to attend. They also streamed the event live, and now provide a recording of the event.

Answer (score 2):

[PNSQC](http://www.pnsqc.org/) (Pacific Northwest) - Mid October - Portland, OR

Comment: I've attended this conference in the past, and I was very impressed by the way it's organized, the speakers, the quality of poster presentations and the networking opportunities.

Comment: Likewise, this is a pretty good conference. Smart attendees. Plus, all of the presentations are backed by a peer-reviewed paper.  Very few "commercial" presentations.

Answer (score 0):

[STAREAST](http://stareast.techwell.com/) - Last week of April to 1st week of May - Orlando, FL, USA

Answer (score 0):

[STARWEST](http://starwest.techwell.com/) - - Last week of September to 1st week of October - Anaheim, CA, USA

Answer (score 0):

The Better Software Conference is held once in the east and once in the west each year, each time in conjunction with an agile conference.

For more information see:

- http://adc-bsc-west.techwell.com/
- http://adc-bsc-east.techwell.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared you a list of conferences in alphabetical order - [conferences](http://www.readyfortest.com/Questions/7370/Conferences-for-QA-or-testers)

Comment: Could you perhaps list your conferences here (or comment on the ones already listed) and use the link for more information? Your answer doesn't do anything towards a community list of conferences here with information about them.

Answer (score 0):

[CAST - Conference of the Association for Software Testing](http://www.associationforsoftwaretesting.org/conference/about-cast/)

> **What makes CAST unique?**
>
> - For testers, by testers
> - We strive to advance and improve the science of software testing
> - We share, discuss, and question
> - Meet industry leaders (authors, bloggers, and personalities)
> - Network with peers, and experts
> - Reasonably priced, high ROI
>
> **Who should attend CAST?**
>
> - Software Testers, Practitioners, and Managers
> - Scholars and Researchers
> - Students
> - Developers
>
>   The core mission of The Association for Software Testing (AST) and
>     CAST is to help build an active community of software testing
>     scholars, practitioners, and learners who can in turn positively
>     influence and advance the practice of software testing.